# Problema com Lógica em Listagem com 3 informações

Tags: php, lógica

estou recebendo do banco de dados vários clientes que possuem contratos e cada contrato desses possui vários documentos... como posso listar isto usando vetores no php? fazem 8 anos que estou longe dos códigos e estou voltando a 1 semana... desculpe minha ignorância... não estou conseguindo resolver esta lógica...

ex:
cli1 - cont1 - doc1 
cli1 - cont1 - doc2 
cli2 - cont1 - doc1 
cli2 - cont2 - doc1 
cli2 - cont2 - doc2

imprimir da seguinte forma:

- Cli1

  - cont1
    - doc1

      doc2

  Cli2

  - cont1
    - doc1

  - cont2
    - doc2

      doc2

fiquei viajando nos vetores e nao consegui nada... por favor... alguém poderia colocar um modelo resolução aqui por favor?? minha lógica foi pro saco!
Obrigado!

galera estou quase lá... entretando, nao aparecem alguns registros... segue o codigo da parte que imprime os documentos do regsitro apenas, ignorando a parte dos clientes pra facilitar a vista e desde já agradeço muito a ajuda _/_:

```
        If($auxCont=="")//primeiro contrato
        {
            $contrato = "ID do Contrato: ".$dados->Campo("IDContrato");
            $html.=ImLinCSS(array($contrato), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContSubOn1");
            $auxCont=$dados->Campo("IDContrato");
        }
        if($auxCont == $dados->Campo("IDContrato")) //se for o mesmo contrato do registro
        {
            //imprime os documentos do contrato
            $doc = $dados->Campo("Descricao");
            $html.=ImLinCSS(array($doc), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContSubOf1");

        }
        else
        {//se for um segundo contrato
            $contrato = "ID do Contrato: ".$dados->Campo("IDContrato");
            $html.=ImLinCSS(array($contrato), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContSubOn1");
            $auxCont=$dados->Campo("IDContrato");
            //imprime o primeiro documento do segundo contrato e adiante
            $doc = $dados->Campo("Descricao");
            $html.=ImLinCSS(array($doc), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContSubOf1");
        }
```

**Resolvido e Otimizado:**

```
$auxCli = ""; //cliente começa sendo nenhum
          $auxCont = ""; //contrato começa sendo nenhum
          while ($dados->LeProxReg())
          {
             if ($auxCli != $dados->Campo("CodCliente")) //Trocou o Cliente
             {
                $cliente = "Código do Cliente: " . $dados->Campo("CodCliente") . " - " . $dados->Campo("Nome");
                if ($dados->Campo("EhPessJuridic") == "S")
                   $cliente .= " - CNPJ" . $dados->Campo("CNPJ");
                else
                   $cliente .= " - CPF" . $dados->Campo("CPF");

                $html .= ImLinCSS(array($cliente), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContOn1");

                If ($auxCont != $dados->Campo("IDContrato")) //trocou contrato
                   $html .= ImLinCSS(array("ID do Contrato: " . $dados->Campo("IDContrato")), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContSubOn1");
             }
             $auxCont = $dados->Campo("IDContrato");
             $auxCli = $dados->Campo("CodCliente");
             $html .= ImLinCSS(array($dados->Campo("Descricao")), $arr_largCol, $arr_alinCol, $lin, "ContSubOf1");
          }
```

Comment: Procura por array multidimensional. Como Iterar, é com `foreach`.

Comment: A lógica, bem resumidamente, é controlar se você já imprimiu cada valor que pode se repetir. Por exemplo, ao passar pela segunda linha de dados do seu exemplo, você não imprime `cli1` nem `cont1`, só `doc2`. Precisa controlar também em que nível da árvore você está.

Comment: Eles vem sempre ordenados, ou a ordem pode estar diferente (salteado)?

Comment: Consegui galera... OBRIGADO!!! Posto a resolução?

Comment: Sim, por favor. Postar a solução é sempre bom porque pode ajudar outras pessoas com problemas similares.